# String concatenation in SQL statement VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am writing a SQL statement as a string in an access VBA macro.  I want to add a dynamic variable into the string statement but I am unsure how to concatenate it correctly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
"CREATE TABLE ThisTable " & _
        "(StateMedicaid TEXT, Commercial TEXT, HIX TEXT, MMP TEXT, CMS Part D (CY " & _ year " TEXT,  CMS Part D (CY " & _ (year+1) " TEXT, );"
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: `"first part " & variableName & " second part"`

Comment: The last comma looks supsicious: "TEXT, );"  Is that causing a syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

just use & for concatenation

```
"CREATE TABLE ThisTable (StateMedicaid TEXT, Commercial TEXT, HIX TEXT, MMP TEXT, CMS Part D (CY" & year &"] TEXT,  CMS Part D ([CY " & (year+1) &"] TEXT );"
```

Notice : 
first

> How & is used and not &_

second

> while naming columns, don't use spaces or use [] if you want to give
>   spaces, I've show both of them. first one removes spaces after CY so
>   that your column name is formed without spaces, and in second one I've
>   included [] so that you column name works with spaces as well
>
> and already pointed out last comma should be omitted

Comment: `"CREATE TABLE ThisTable (StateMedicaid TEXT, Commercial TEXT, HIX TEXT, MMP TEXT, CMSPartDCY" & year & " TEXT,  CMSPartDCY " & (year + 1) & " TEXT )"` This is what I put in and it is causing a syntax error in the field definition.

Comment: "CMSPartDCY " & (year + 1)"" is whats causing you problem, notice the space after Y

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible to use parentheses in the field names? I was confused by your explanation in the answer above.

Comment: It is, but is highly recommended not to use them as it will simply make things more complex (also mentioned by @HansUp). Still if you are so much into differentiating the year from text use _ instead. And I'll try to be better at explanations next time onwards. You see writing down explanation is not something I am good at. :P

Answer (score 1):

Codeek described the problems in your `CREATE TABLE` statement.  Still it can be easy to misplace the required `[]` brackets when dealing with a field name which contains spaces and punctuation characters.  (Actually, Access development is easier if you can avoid spaces and punctuation in object names.)

I add a line break after each field definition to make it easier for me to spot problems.  Here is the statement produced by the following code sample. I tested it in Access 2010 and it executed without error.

```sql
CREATE TABLE ThisTable (
    StateMedicaid TEXT,
    Commercial TEXT,
    HIX TEXT,
    MMP TEXT,
    [CMS Part D (CY 2015)] TEXT,
    [CMS Part D (CY 2016)] TEXT
    );
```

```vb
Dim strCreate As String
Dim intYear As String
intYear = 2015

strCreate = "CREATE TABLE ThisTable (" & vbCrLf & _
            "StateMedicaid TEXT," & vbCrLf & _
            "Commercial TEXT," & vbCrLf & _
            "HIX TEXT," & vbCrLf & _
            "MMP TEXT," & vbCrLf & _
            "[CMS Part D (CY " & intYear & ")] TEXT," & vbCrLf & _
            "[CMS Part D (CY " & (intYear + 1) & ")] TEXT" & vbCrLf & _
            ");"
Debug.Print strCreate
```

Note I changed the variable name from *year* to *intYear* because there is a function named `Year()`.